# Android Studio AVD causes avd to crash and AS closes without warning

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm running latest beta Android Studio 4.2 Beta 3. Each time I try to click on the run button to start my AVD, the AVD does not start and will cause Android Studio to crash. I do not have HAXM installed and I am running MacOS Catalina (10.15.7 (19H114))

Trying to run emulator from terminal causes this to print out:

```
emulator: Android emulator version 30.4.1.0 (build_id 7075546) (CL:N/A)
handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
cannot add library /Users/weijie/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed
added library /Users/weijie/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib
cannot add library /Users/weijie/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libMoltenVK.dylib: failed
added library /Users/weijie/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libMoltenVK.dylib
zsh: terminated  ./emulator -avd Pixel_3a_API_30_x86
```

I would appreciate any suggestions from the community. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Same issue here :/

Answer (score 7):

Change two lines in this file:
`~/.android/avd/Pixel_3_API_29.avd/config.ini`

```
hw.gpu.enabled = yes
hw.gpu.mode = software
```

Replace "Pixel_3_API_29" with whatever the name of your image is. It has something to do with Vulkan and Metal. I guess the Android Studio developers aren't testing their software updates on older Macs.