# Android emulator with Vulkan is not rendering dialogs correctly

Tags: android, android-emulator, render, vulkan

I am starting an Android Emulator via console like this: `./emulator -avd Pixel_6a_API_34 -feature -Vulkan`. When using the app, I found, that all dialogs are shown without dark background/shadow. On the left side of the screenshot below you see how it is supposed to look (captured on real Pixel 6a API 34) and on the right side is how emulator with Vulkan is rendering it. Any ideas how to fix?

Screenshot or a video for better understanding ([click](https://youtube.com/shorts/_CyJ0_q5lao))
[image]

I tried to find a solution on SO, but didnt manage to do so. Anyway, would appreciate a link to solution

Answer (score 0):

Originally, i had a problem with Chrome Browser not working on API 34 on emulator, so had that work-around in the original question. However, here is the fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66284962/14762516